# Generating a list of paths to files in directories, MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have some files that all have the same name, say 'file.nii', there are 60 of these files, and each file resides within a specific directory.

The structure goes `/Users/name/DirC2133/nDir/file.nii` where the structure will always be in the form `/Users/name/DirC{4 integers here}/nDir/file.nii`. So lets say something like this:

```
/Users/name/DirC3065/nDir/file.nii
/Users/name/DirC3067/nDir/file.nii
/Users/name/DirC3078/nDir/file.nii
/Users/name/DirC3156/nDir/file.nii
/Users/name/DirC3546/nDir/file.nii
.....
```

And so on. I want to store each full path to file.nii for later use. How do I do this with MATLAB? There are also other files inside nDir, but I only want the path to file.nii

In pseudo code I guess it would be something like:

```
for i in 1:60
file[i] = /Users/name/DirC%/nDir/file.nii
```

Comment: `d = dir('/Users/name/DirC*');`

Comment: i get index exceeds matrix dimensions when i try this

Comment: it means u have a `dir` variable in the workspace. Do not overwrite function names with variable. Clear the dir variablea and call it smt ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the IDs of the files and just want to create the strings you can do something like this.

```
image_num_list = [3065,3067,3078,3156,3546]
container = cell(length(image_num_list),1);
for i=1:length(image_num_list)
     container{i}=sprintf('/Users/name/DirC%04d/nDir/file.nii',image_num_list(i))
end
```

If you want to do list the directory recursively you can't do this in matlab with a single dir call, you can use this code:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32226-recursive-directory-listing-enhanced-rdir

In case, by chance, you are using SPM it has its functions to select nii and related files:

```
spm_select
        File selector
  FORMAT [t,sts] = spm_select(n,typ,mesg,sel,wd,filt,frames)
      n    - Number of files
             A single value or a range.  e.g.
             1       - Select one file
             Inf     - Select any number of files
             [1 Inf] - Select 1 to Inf files
             [0 1]   - select 0 or 1 files
             [10 12] - select from 10 to 12 files
      typ  - file type
            'any'   - all files
            'image' - Image files (".img" and ".nii")
                      Note that it gives the option to select
                      individual volumes of the images.
            'mesh'  - Surface mesh files (".gii" or ".mat")
            'xml'   - XML files
            'mat'   - Matlab .mat files or .txt files (assumed to contain
                      ASCII representation of a 2D-numeric array)
            'batch' - SPM batch files (.m, .mat and XML)
            'dir'   - select a directory
            Other strings act as a filter to regexp.  This means
            that e.g. DCM*.mat files should have a typ of '^DCM.*\.mat$'
       mesg - a prompt (default 'Select files...')
       sel  - list of already selected files
       wd   - Directory to start off in
       filt - value for user-editable filter (default '.*')
       frames - Image frame numbers to include (default '1')

       t    - selected files
       sts  - status (1 means OK, 0 means window quit)

  FORMAT [t,ind] = spm_select('Filter',files,typ,filt,frames)
  filter the list of files (cell or char array) in the same way as the
  GUI would do. There is an additional typ 'extimage' which will match
  images with frame specifications, too. Also, there is a typ 'extdir',
  which will match canonicalised directory names. The 'frames' argument
  is currently ignored, i.e. image files will not be filtered out if
  their frame numbers do not match.
  t returns the filtered list (cell or char array, depending on input),
  ind an index array, such that t = files{ind}, or t = files(ind,:).

  FORMAT cpath = spm_select('CPath',path,cwd)
  function to canonicalise paths: Prepends cwd to relative paths, processes
  '..' & '.' directories embedded in path.
  path     - string matrix containing path name
  cwd      - current working directory [default '.']
  cpath    - conditioned paths, in same format as input path argument

  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('List',direc,filt)
  Returns files matching the filter (filt) and directories within direc
  direc    - directory to search
  filt     - filter to select files with (see regexp) e.g. '^w.*\.img$'
  files    - files matching 'filt' in directory 'direc'
  dirs     - subdirectories of 'direc'

  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('ExtList',direc,filt,frames)
  As above, but for selecting frames of 4D NIfTI files
  frames   - vector of frames to select (defaults to 1, if not
             specified). If the frame number is Inf, all frames for the
             matching images are listed. 

  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('FPList',direc,filt)
  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('ExtFPList',direc,filt,frames)
  As above, but returns files with full paths (i.e. prefixes direc to each)
  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('FPListRec',direc,filt)
  FORMAT [files,dirs] = spm_select('ExtFPListRec',direc,filt,frames)
  As above, but returns files with full paths (i.e. prefixes direc to
  each) and searches through sub directories recursively.

  FORMAT spm_select('prevdirs',dir)
  Add directory dir to list of previous directories.
  FORMAT dirs = spm_select('prevdirs')
  Retrieve list of previous directories.
```